# Create hidden service of remote virtual host

Tags: onion-services

I need to create a hidden service of a website accessible thru my home lan network, from my PC (192.168.1.54) where Tor is also running, I connect to mywebsite.com,
mywebsite.com points to 192.168.1.56 (I know cause I've pinged it). The problem is that http://mywebsite.com is a virtualhost so if I create a hidden service to 192.168.1.56:80 when I connect to it thru the browser it gives me an error because 192.168.1.56:80 doesen't view mywebsite.com but only z random error page. The main issue is that I don't have access to the webservers config, because 192.168.1.56 is a closed box (It looks like a router) and not a PC, so I can't modify the apache (or whatever it uses) making ports like I've read you have to do to make a hidden service of a virtual host.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Typically what one does when you want to have tor on one machine and then the webserver on another is to run for example apache on both machines, then when people connect to the one which hosts the tor domain it will then forward the connection to the other webserver.

This enables you to easily isolate the webserver from everything else.
This is how it's done in for example the 'Whonix' gateway.

There are examples for this setup type here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/126704/how-do-i-point-one-virtual-host-to-another-instance-of-apache-running-at-another

Comment: hi tnx for your kind reply, i'm using http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/116-simple-apache-reverse-proxy-example and it works, but i'd like to point tor to http://127.0.0.1/site2 rather than http://localhost, infact i aready got folders and webpages in / that i'd like to use in tor, if i write  <Location /site2> it gives me an error, it only works if i use  <Location />, but under / ive got many folder so when i access http://127.0.0.1 it goes to site 2 and i cant see nothing of the othe rfolder anymore

Comment: it doesent work anyway, at least it works to connect to remote ip but not to the url, so if the remote ip has virtualhosts they won't show up

Comment: try to play with DNS for your "black box" and a reverse proxy